# How to put end of file as a condition in the condition to escape from while statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, pymysql

When I update data in a column called 'mine' where all rows are null values in mysql with Python, I want to escape the while statement when there are no more null values. What condition should I add to the query statement below? The current data is updated normally, but when all data is updated, the indication that it is over is not displayed.

```
import pymysql

conn=pymysql.connect(
user='root',
passwd='*',
host='',
db='practice',
charset='utf8')

curs = conn.cursor()

num = 0
while num >= 0:
    num += 1
    sql = "update zipcode set mine = %s where mine is null limit 1"
    data = (num)
    curs.execute(sql, data)
    conn.commit()

conn.close()
```